# как отсортировать map по значениям

Tags: java, map

У меня есть

```
map<String, Integer>;
```

нужно отсортировать по значениям, как это можно сделать?

Comment: какой язык-то?.

Comment: учитывая, что мап обычно не последовательный контейнер, а ассоциативный, подозреваю, что человеку нужен либо вывод, либо итераторы

Comment: @KoVadim, в ну принципе есть и [sorted](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) если конечно речь про яву :)

Comment: да язык java извиняюсь запарился за день чего-то) значится Interface SortedMap<K,V> но разве он сортирует по значениям? мне нужно отсортировать значения, не ключи.

Comment: а нашел решение map.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Map.Entry.<K, Integer>comparingByValue().reversed())